# How to optimize OSM vector data in DB?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, editing, spatialite

I am using offline OSM data for the area of the Czech Republic in my project (freely available for [download here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/etu8hf40sz5cbgw/QGIS_2016_vzorovy_projekt_2016_03_08.7z)). I am using the OSM data in Spatialite + EU-DEM derived contour lines - only as background map.

[image: my offline data from OSM]

It is relatively slow even on powerful PCs. I searched for a way to improve the performance and Martin Dobias advised me to optimize the vector data and keep it as vectors.

I plan to reproject the data to EPSG:3857 - to match project CRS and not to complicate switching between offline maps and online via Openlayers.

I would also like to clean the OSM data - remove all unused fields and make it possible to use categorized renderer instead of rule-based renderer.

Is there any user-friendly way to work with the fields similarly to attribute table tools? I found the DB structure quite confusing for me.

Or is it easier to edit directly the OSM format and modify the data structure before conversion to QGIS DB?

Until now I only used CLI commands found in some tutorials to convert OSM to DB.

Comment: What format is your OSM data in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187101/how-to-speed-up-work-with-local-maps-in-qgis. Please don't ask the same twice. You can still edit your first question.

Comment: Then for me would be better to close the first question where I did not even know whether to use raster or vector layers etc. This one is about vector data in DB only.

Answer (score 2):

The OSM data runs quite fast here, but the simplification of highways looks a bit ugly at motorway junctions. You should render minor roads scale dependent, no need to see them on a nationwide scale.

You can leave out the multilinestring table, it contains only route relations. The highways that are part of the routes are already in the lines table. I suggest to use the multilinestrings after simplification for low zoom levels, and keep the lines from the original dataset without simplification.

The contour lines are rather slow. You should add spatial indices to the table.

Dropping of columns does not necessarily speed up things, while indices on heavy used columns like highway or landuse might do.

Comment: Thanks, I also though about multilinestring table - whether it has sense to keep it or not. I will have a more detailed look on the junction. In my case even on i5 with 16GB RAM it becames slow when I load measurements reaching across half of the country. Looks I need to create some low-detailed layer for certain scale range.

Comment: That's what osm2pgsql does for low zoom levels. I guess you won't need landuse there either. Mapnik uses the populated places from Natural Earth to replace OSM residential landuse for low zoom levels.

Comment: You can have a look at [these styles](https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/) that have scale dependent rules for osm data.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try my styles as well: https://github.com/Andre-J/QGIS-OpenStreetMap-Styles. Designed for use with Postgis, but should be rather similar with spatialite.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but what works for me is doing the import from OSM with ogr2ogr and a modified osmconf.ini file.
Here is the script I use to import from overpass-api to sqlite:

wget -O map.osm "http://overpass-api.de/api/map?bbox=2.6500,41.9000,3.0031,42.1000" && ogr2ogr --config OSM_CONFIG_FILE /home/user/route/to/osmconf.ini -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES output.sqlite map.osm

I made a copy of /usr/share/gdal/osmconf.ini to my home directory, edited it to import the tags needed and pointed the script to it.
Of course the bounding box (bbox) has to be changed to your needs.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

With these contours as part of your basemap, it is quite likely the main problem is not with the OSM data, but with the contour data itself. Raw contours calculated from a DEM can have huge features with many vertices. The best thing to do is to first smooth the contours using some kind of generalization process, weeding out spurious vertices. Then "dice" or cut up your contour dataset by overlaying it with some rectangular grid polygon dataset. This will ensure that no extremely long contour lines are present. Lastly, create a proper spatial index.

As to the OSM data itself: besides creating proper spatial indexes and generalization, a process like a spatial sort (as you can do in e.g. ArcGIS - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/sort.htm), may help as well to speed up data access.